# Layout issue for android phones with bottom action bar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I am having an issue with android phones having a bottom action bar where the app screen is being cut off by the action bar in the phone. Please see the screenshot below which better describes my issue. The button is being cut off by the actionbar.

[image: The button at the bottom of my app screen is cut off by the action bar]

Below is my layout xml file.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/root_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@mipmap/main_bg"
    tools:context="com.myapp.SeatsActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/actionbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/irctc_actionbar_height"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
            android:onClick="onClickgoHome"
            android:src="@mipmap/iconhome" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button11"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView4"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="SEAT AVAILABILITY"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView5"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/irctc_actionbar_height"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/irctc_actionbar_height"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@drawable/trans_button"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:onClick="onClickShare"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@mipmap/share" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button11"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView5"
            android:onClick="onClickDate"
            android:text="date:"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/horizontal_line"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/actionbar_layout"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:orientation="vertical" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtview_trainname"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/horizontal_line"
        android:background="@color/irctc_menu_bg_color"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Train Name"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/hr2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtview_trainname"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:orientation="vertical" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtview_fromtostation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/hr2"
        android:background="@color/irctc_menu_bg_color"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Station Name"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/hr3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtview_fromtostation"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:orientation="vertical" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_table_header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="46dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/hr3"
        android:background="@color/irctc_menu_bg_color"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Date"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtview_class1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="class1"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtview_class2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="class2"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_bottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btn_express_book"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
        android:background="@color/irctc_menu_bg_color">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView9"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Quota:"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_quota"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView9"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView9"
            android:background="@drawable/trans_button"
            android:onClick="onClickQuota"
            android:text="Selected Quota"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="@drawable/trans_button"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:onClick="onClickTrainSchedule"
            android:paddingBottom="4dp"
            android:paddingTop="4dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@mipmap/train_schedule" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView9"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView8"
            android:background="@drawable/trans_button"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:onClick="onClickFareEnquery"
            android:paddingBottom="4dp"
            android:paddingTop="4dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@mipmap/fair_enquiry" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview_seatcell"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/layout_table_header" />

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/layout_bottom"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_express_book"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:background="@drawable/irctc_button"
        android:onClick="onClickExpressBook"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"

        android:paddingLeft="40dp"
        android:paddingRight="40dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:text="Express Book!"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Am I doing something wrong here? What changes would I need to make to the xml to accommodate phones with an action bar ?

Comment: Why are you having `LinearLayout`  with `id=hr2` and `id=hr3` ,when there are no views inside it. It is useless to have them.

Comment: Did you try using a scrollview?

Comment: The issue is not the small screen size here so using a scrollview wont help. The issue is that the button is aligned to the parent bottom but is still cut off.

Answer (score 1):

Try Setting android:layout_alignParentBottom="false" to android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" inside of the layout. So something like this.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_bottom"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/btn_express_book"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@color/irctc_menu_bg_color">
```

Comment: I already set `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` for the Button. You mean set it for the relativelayout as well?

Comment: yes try it in the relative layout, sorry my post wasn't clear

Answer (score 1):

I've already add `ScrollView` to your ViewGroup. Check it:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/root_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@mipmap/main_bg"
    tools:context="com.myapp.SeatsActivity">

<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/actionbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/irctc_actionbar_height"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
            android:onClick="onClickgoHome"
            android:src="@mipmap/iconhome" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button11"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView4"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="SEAT AVAILABILITY"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView5"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/irctc_actionbar_height"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/irctc_actionbar_height"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@drawable/trans_button"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:onClick="onClickShare"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@mipmap/share" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button11"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView5"
            android:onClick="onClickDate"
            android:text="date:"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/horizontal_line"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/actionbar_layout"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:orientation="vertical" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtview_trainname"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/horizontal_line"
        android:background="@color/irctc_menu_bg_color"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Train Name"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/hr2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtview_trainname"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:orientation="vertical" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtview_fromtostation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/hr2"
        android:background="@color/irctc_menu_bg_color"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Station Name"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/hr3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtview_fromtostation"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:orientation="vertical" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_table_header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="46dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/hr3"
        android:background="@color/irctc_menu_bg_color"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Date"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtview_class1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="class1"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtview_class2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="class2"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_bottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btn_express_book"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
        android:background="@color/irctc_menu_bg_color">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView9"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Quota:"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_quota"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView9"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView9"
            android:background="@drawable/trans_button"
            android:onClick="onClickQuota"
            android:text="Selected Quota"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="@drawable/trans_button"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:onClick="onClickTrainSchedule"
            android:paddingBottom="4dp"
            android:paddingTop="4dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@mipmap/train_schedule" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView9"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView8"
            android:background="@drawable/trans_button"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:onClick="onClickFareEnquery"
            android:paddingBottom="4dp"
            android:paddingTop="4dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@mipmap/fair_enquiry" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview_seatcell"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/layout_table_header" />

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/layout_bottom"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_express_book"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:background="@drawable/irctc_button"
        android:onClick="onClickExpressBook"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"

        android:paddingLeft="40dp"
        android:paddingRight="40dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:text="Express Book!"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

  </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Hope it help

Comment: The issue is not the small screen size here. The issue is that the button is aligned to the parent bottom but is still cut off.

Comment: The same issue occurs on a big phone screen like the Nexus 6p. I know using scrollview would fix the issue but i'm trying to find a solution without using a scrollview.

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't use `RelativeLayout` to imitate `LinearLayout`.

None of your views overlap, and none of them need need any kind of special alignment with other views. Recreating that with `layout_below` and `layout_above` is confusing. Everything you have in your layout can be done with `LinearLayout`s instead and will be much clearer, except for maybe the two action bars (but even those might be possible with `LinearLayout`s too).

2. Don't use empty `LinearLayout`s as horizontal dividers.

If you have to use a view at all, just use `View`. But if you are doing this inside of a `LinearLayout` as I suggest in #1, then you might not need views at all, you could use

```
android:showDividers="middle"
android:divider="@drawable/hr"
```

and in `res/drawable/hr.xml`

```
<shape android:shape="rectangle">
    <size android:height="1dp" />
    <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
</shape>
```

3. Don't ever use `wrap_content` as the height of a `ListView`.

`ListView` doesn't know anything about its children. Telling it to be as tall as it needs to contain them doesn't make any sense, and `ListView` is just going to try to guess. You should always use either a static value, `match_parent`, or allow it to fill some arbitrary space using `layout_weight` (if using `LinearLayout`) or other view boundaries (if using `RelativeLayout).

---

Combining all of the above, I think your layout should end up looking like this (only the relevant parts are shown):

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" ...>
    <RelativeLayout ... /> <!-- Top action bar -->
    <TextView ... />
    <TextView ... />
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" ... /> <!-- table header -->
    <ListView
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        ... />
    <AdView ... />
    <RelativeLayout ... /> <!-- bottom action bar -->
    <Button ... /> <!-- The one that is currently cut off -->
</LinearLayout>
```